# Suspicious warnings on Tensorflow 1.0

Tags: tensorflow

Installing the brand new Tensorflow 1.0 from PyPI on Windows, and running the [Hello World example](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#validate_your_installation), I get a bunch of suspicious warnings:

```
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "CountExtremelyRandomStats" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: CountExtremelyRandomStats
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "FinishedNodes" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: FinishedNodes
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "GrowTree" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GrowTree
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ReinterpretStringToFloat" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ReinterpretStringToFloat
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "SampleInputs" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SampleInputs
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ScatterAddNdim" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScatterAddNdim
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNInsert" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNInsert
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNRemove" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNRemove
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TreePredictions" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TreePredictions
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "UpdateFertileSlots" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: UpdateFertileSlots
```

But after the warnings, "Hello World" does get printed. Should I worry?

Comment: I hit the same error.  And now my Tensorflow is broken.  All of my solutions fail with errors like ' module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'mul' '.Something

Comment: It's a problem with Windows that we fixed recently. Please update and try again.

Comment: @drpng will the fix make it to PyPI?

Comment: Have same problem after rebuilding numpy with MKL (possibly related?).

Comment: @JerryKur in r1.0 update they have moved a lot of namespaces arround, you need to update it (i.e. tf.mul is now tf.multiply).
[Check here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration) for more details. You can also use their script to upgrade files and folders [from here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/compatibility)

Comment: Thanks umutto.  Appreciate the info

Comment: @KurokiKaze I use numpy+mkl.